# Woocommerce BCC customer order confirmation

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have earlier been using this snippet to send a bcc mail with the customer order confirmation to an extra e-mail address:

```
// Add custom BCC mail to completed orders
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_headers', 'mycustom_headers_filter_function', 10, 2);
function mycustom_headers_filter_function( $headers, $object ) {
    if ($object == 'customer_completed_order') {
        $headers .= 'BCC: NAME <name@domain.com>' . "\r\n";
    }

    return $headers;
}
```

This somehow doesn't work any more after the last update? Someone got a clue why and assist me with a fix?

Best regards

Comment: Not sure, because that filter is still in place.

Comment: where did you add the filter?

Comment: It is added in the functions.php file